# Numbers formatted using scientific notation in the MSFlexGrid on Windows 7

Tags: windows, vb6, number-formatting, msflexgrid

I installed a vb6 application on windows seven and office 2010.

This application works fine on xp/vista with Ms access 2007.

The MsflexGrid shows wrong numbers on win seven with the sign "E" like 4526E ...

What could be the problem. is it access 2010?

Comment: How are the numbers formatted under winXP and Vista?

Comment: First check if this is caused by the video adapter's DPI setting, causing the numbers to no longer fit the box.  Next check if this reproduces on another machine, if not then check the regional format overrides in control panel.  Next start thinking about running this ancient code in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1.2E+34` is a perfectly valid format when a number contains lots of significant zeros:

```
?cdbl(12000000000000000000000000000000000)
 1.2E+34
```

Does the same grid differ when showing the same data?

Where are the numbers coming from? If they're being added by code (vs data bound) then you can use `Format()` to use an explicit format string rather than letting Windows do what it thinks is best.

Comment: Does the same grid differ when showing the same data? : YES. I will try the format. thanks.

Comment: Hi all, If a want to keep the english regional parameters, how to change de Ms access database to english format number?